# DDD model of a purchase in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ddd

I already have some experience with Java and I'm used to modeling with a DDD approach. Therefore, now I'm beginning with JS and NodeJS and I'd like to know which is the best practice to design with a similar approach in Javascript (without ES6).

Here I have an example of what I'm trying to do, but I don't know if these is the better way. I appreciate some opinions.

```
function Purchase(pCustomer, pOrders, pPayment, pTotal) {
    let idPurchase = PurchaseId.purchaseId();
    let customer = pCustomer;
    let payment = pPayment;
    let orders = pOrders;
    let deliveryAddress;
    let billingAddress;
    let total = pTotal;

    // Return an object exposed to the public
    return {
        setOrders: function (o) {
            orders = o
        },
        setDeliveryAddress: function (address1, address2, zipCode, city) {
            deliveryAddress = new Address(address1, address2, zipCode, city);
        },
        setBillingAddress: function (address1, address2, zipCode, city) {
            billingAddress = new Address(address1, address2, zipCode, city);
        },
        getId: function () {
            return idPurchase;
        },
        getOrders: function () {
            return orders;
        },
        getCustomer: function () {
            return customer;
        },
        toJSON: function () {
            return {
                idPurchase: idPurchase,
                customerOnPurchase: customer.toJSON(),
                deliveryAddress: deliveryAddress.toJSON(),
                billingAddress: billingAddress.toJSON(),
                total: total,
            }
        }
    }
}

module.exports = Purchase;
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on functions like `getId` and `toJSON`, it seems like you would naturally want to have a base class for your models. As such, it would make sense to write your functions in a way that support prototypical inheritance e.g.

**Base Model**

```
function Entity(id) {
  this._id = id;
}

Entity.prototype = {
  function getId() {
    return this._id;
  }
  ...
}

module.exports = Entity;
```

**Derived Model**

```
var Entity = require('./entity');
var util = require('util');

function Purchase(customer, orders, ...) {
  Entity.call(this, PurchaseId.purchaseId());
  this._customer = customer;
  this._orders = orders;
  ...
}

util.inherits(Purchase, Entity);

Purchase.prototype.getCustomer = function() {
  return this._customer;
}
Purchase.prototype.getOrders = function() {
  return this._orders;
}
...
module.exports = Purchase;
```

**Usage**

```
var purchase = new Purchase(...);
console.log(purchase.getId()); // Purchase will inherit everything from Entity
console.log(purchase.getCustomer()); // and have it's own functions too
```

*Note - notice in base we set the `prototype` directly but in the derived we modify it? This is deliberate because in the base class the prototype is currently empty so it's fine to completely overwrite. If we did the same thing on the derived class then we'd lose the base prototype therefore we simply append to the existing prototype.*